# Is it possible to create a shortcut to a folder with InstallShield 2010?

Tags: installshield

I'm using an InstallShield 2010 InstallScript project. I want to make a shortcut to a folder.

I've tried setting the Target to path of the folder. This creates a shortcut but it has a `Target Type` of FILE. How can I create a shortcut to the folder with a `Target Type` of FOLDER?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have not found a way to make a Folder type shortcut, but I did find a pretty good workaround.

What you can do is to make a file link to explorer with a command line argument of the folder you want to open.

```
Target: %SYSTEMROOT%\explorer.exe
Arguments: "<TARGETDIR>\My Folder"
```

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE for InstallShield 2012 Limited Edition:

1. On the project navigation panel on the left, Open the tab "3. Configure the Target System" + "Shortcut and Folders"
2. Right button on existing shortcuts: Click on option "New Shortcut to Preexisting file"
3. On the right panel (detail properties): 
   Target= [WindowsFolder]explorer.exe
   Arguments= [MyPicturesFOlder]MyNewFolder

The new link will open up in MyNewFolder in user's pictures folder !

Many thanks to msergeant !

Comment: The OP specified an InstallScript project which isn't supported by InstallShield Limited Edition.

Answer (score 1):

I found that the workaround with explore.exe has some side-effects.  It does create a functional shortcut to the target folder, but in my case (IS 2010, Windows 7 64-bits) it creates in a 'roaming' directory...

*C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\companyname*

... instead of the usual directory:

*C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\companyname*